# SignalStrength has methods based on mobile connection type. How do I know which to use?

Tags: android

In my application, TelephonyManager has a PhoneStateListener set to listen to LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS. I get a call to onSignalStrengthsChanged and get the SignalStrength. But since SignalStrength has multiple methods for getting the signal strength, (for cdma, evdo and gsm) I'm not sure which one to use.

How do I correctly determine which of cmda, evdo and gsm methods to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GSM, the signal strength structure has a isGsm flag. If it's true, then you know it's GSM and can ignore the others.

When isGsm is false, apparently the use of cdma and evdo is carrier specific. Some carrier uses cmda for voice, evdo for data or vice versa. In short, there appears to be no way to determine programmatically which one is being used for data. As I'm not an expert on this, I could very well be wrong.